# Basic swift layout having centred view with labels and text within by program

Tags: ios, swift, layout

Why does this code gives out nothing when run? I want 2 labels, 2 textfield and a button to sit in view (**container**) which centred within the main view. Now when run the screen is plain white nothing there.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // User ID label
    let userIDLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    userIDLabel.text = "User ID"

    // Password label
    let passwordLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    passwordLabel.text = "Password"

    // User ID text
    let userIDText:UITextField = UITextField()

    // Password text
    let passwordText:UITextField = UITextField()

    // Login button
    let loginBtn:UIButton = UIButton()
    loginBtn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)

    // Container view
    let container:UIView = UIView()
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    container.addSubview(userIDLabel)
    container.addSubview(userIDText)
    container.addSubview(passwordLabel)
    container.addSubview(passwordText)
    container.addSubview(loginBtn)

    view.addSubview(container)


    // Add constraints
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 300)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
    let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    container.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    container.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
    view.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)
    view.addConstraint(centerYConstraint)

}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks everyone. Now there the objects are showing after adding frames

```
    // User ID label
    let userIDLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 50.0))
    userIDLabel.text = "User ID"
    // Password label
    let passwordLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 30.0, width: 200.0, height: 30.0))
    passwordLabel.text = "Password"
    // User ID text
    let userIDText:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 60.0, width: 200.0, height: 30.0))
    // Password text
    let passwordText:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 90.0, width: 200.0, height: 30.0))
    // Login button
    let loginBtn:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 120.0, width: 100.0, height: 30.0))
    loginBtn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
```

But the container is not **vertically align** to relative to the view as I would like to. The **height/width** of the view is fixed for now. Is there a way to make it **dynamic**, so that it knows the height it needed to hold all the labels and texts? I don not want to hardcode height/width.

**Can height of view(grey backgroud) dynamic?**

[image]

Comment: You should probably add constraints to your label, textfield and button and also a frame!

Comment: there is no such thing as default frame size?

Comment: not really. You should specify a frame or constraints for those views inside your contentView. Or maybe use a UIStackView for automatic arrangement? It depends on what you want

Comment: i find it difficult to arrange object in swift using only program. painful

Comment: Use a stackview! what kind of arrangement do you want? if you want everything aligned vertically for instance you could achieve this with a stackview very easily

Comment: You didn't set frame to the container view.

Comment: i changed let container:UIView = UIView() to UIStackView, still nothing

Comment: @ClintonLam you need to add container view as subview of main view after that you can show container view.

Comment: @HarshalValanda i did, view.addSubview(container)

Comment: @ClintonLam change the background color of container view or set constraints or frame for container's subviews

Comment: @ClintonLam its not just changing to stackview but you need to add your views inside and setting the stackview. Maybe it would be helpful if you edit your question and tell us what exactly are you expecting as an output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using anchors. They always work perfect for me.

```
let someView = UIView()
someView.backgroundColor = .red
someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(someView)
someView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
someView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
someView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
someView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

**Important**: note that `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` should be set fale **for the view that your are trying to center**

**EDIT:**
You also need to set size and constraints to your labels and fields. Currently you don't have any frames for them. You can also instantiate the labels or fields with frames:

```
UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add frames to Label, text field, button, and container view.

Comment: is there a default size of frame?

Comment: @ClintonLam no, there is no. check my answer.

Comment: there is no default size of frame.

Answer (score 1):

set frame of `label`, `textfield` and `button`. you can also set constraints

Try this for `container`:

```
 container.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
 view.addSubview(container)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview), perfectly fit for this type of layouts. Don't need to add constraints :)

**Bonus**: If you even want a scrollable solution there is a third party library on GitHub: [ScrollableStackView](https://github.com/gurhub/ScrollableStackView)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to add objects in to **UIView**, you will need to specify **frame** for each of the objects to be added. Sample below.

   ```
   UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 50.0))
   ```
2. If you want **autoresizing**, **UIStackView** would be the solution. You don't have to define frame for the object to be added. Following is the code using **UIStackView** (container).

   ```
   // User ID label
   let userIDLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
   userIDLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
   userIDLabel.text = "User ID"

   // Password label
   let passwordLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
   passwordLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
   passwordLabel.text = "Password"

   // User ID text
   let userIDText:UITextField = UITextField()
   userIDText.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

   // Password text
   let passwordText:UITextField = UITextField()
   passwordText.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

   // Login button
   let loginBtn:UIButton = UIButton()
   loginBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
   loginBtn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)

   // Container view
   let container:UIStackView = UIStackView()
   container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   container.axis = .vertical

   container.addArrangedSubview(userIDLabel)
   container.addArrangedSubview(userIDText)
   container.addArrangedSubview(passwordLabel)
   container.addArrangedSubview(passwordText)
   container.addArrangedSubview(loginBtn)

   view.addSubview(container)

   // Add constraints
   let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
   let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

   view.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)
   view.addConstraint(centerYConstraint)
   ```

Here is the result. **StackView** **centred** within the main view with labels and textfields within.

**Vertical Orientation**

[image]

**Horizontal Orientation**

[image]